# AngularJS execute code when changing pages that use same controller

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a PhoneGap app, that has multiple html pages.

I use one controller, called AppController, that loads the data for the startup screen and default pages.

I added a new page to the navigation bar, which, when clicked & opened should load up data from the server with a php call, so it should only make a php call, when the page is shown.

This page uses the same controller as the rest of the app.

I am really new to AngularJS, so I might've programmed it in a bad way, but the rest of the data for the home page is loaded in the appController like this

```
myApp.controller('AppController', function ($scope, $timeout, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.items= {};
    $scope.items[item1] = {....} //LOADING UP the items collection
}
```

How can I hook up an "onload" event or something, that would only fire when the page is shown?

Comment: And why not using $location service - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location?

Comment: controller code runs exactly when it becomes shown

Comment: `$rootScope.on('$routeChangeSuccess', cb)` may be useful also.

Comment: If you're using ng-view, see ng-view's $viewContentLoaded event.  Don't forget to hook the 'deviceready' and 'online' event to ensure you can access the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways you could do that, one of them:

```
// inside your controller
angular.element(document).ready(function () {

// your code 

});
```

another one:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="someinitfunc()"></div>
```

Comment: I used ng-init! Thank you!

Comment: Since you could be using routes, the proper way is the first one.

Answer (score 0):

How about using ng-init() directive on your next page ?